# How to determine font packages used from .log, .out, etc

Tags: fontspec

Texlive/pdflatex used to produce documents I really liked the look of, which was like this:

[image]

I have since reverted to the defaults:

[image]

Is there any way to look in the .out/.log/etc files that produced the first pdf to try to reproduce that look?

Comment: Do you still have the first pdf?

Comment: pdffonts utility or your viewer font menu will be able to tell you the fonts in the old pdf. If you still have the old.log file you know exactly which packages were used.

Comment: Thanks very much!  pdffonts gave me the answer:

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mlmodern}

Comment: @BenHarland That's never been the default. `mlmodern` is *newer*. However, it is designed to look more like Computer Modern (e.g. heavier) than Latin Modern. So that may be why it looks the-way-it-used-to-be.  On the other hand, you don't get Latin Modern by default with pdfTeX either. So it's probably the (later) vector versus (earlier) bitmap Computer Modern you have in mind?

Comment: As far as I can remember, I've always had CM or LM as default on my standard Fedora distribution of TexLive.  Less than a year ago, after a system reinstall, I started producing MLModern somehow.  I much prefer the look of that, so wanted to find out how to get it back.

I would have saved myself considerable time if I had just gone here first:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern